# Obtain a QImage or QPixmap from QStandardItemModel - TableView

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if there was a way of obtaining an image displayed on cell on a table in a way like this.Does QStandardItemModel have any methods that could assist ?

```
QImage p =  MyQStandardItemModelptr->item(row,col)->data();
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following call:

```
QImage p = MyQStandardItemModelptr->item(row,col)->data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QImage>();
```

Please note the usage of `Qt::DecorationRole`.

Comment: could u tell me what the index is ? I have the row and the col of the QstandardItemModel ?

Comment: Sorry, there is only one argument for `QStandardItem::data()`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: I get `rror C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'QVariant' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` should it be type-casted ?